# MySQL stored procedure not returning correct results

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that checks if a user exists already, regardless of the input used for the email it comes back with the first line in the database. If I run the select statements manually I get the correct results. Any suggestions why?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`myusername`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `User_Auth`(IN `Email` VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    DECLARE User_ID INT(30);
        SELECT `User ID` INTO User_ID FROM `Users` WHERE `Email` = Email LIMIT 1;

    IF (User_ID > 0) THEN
        SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `User ID` = User_ID;
    ELSE
        SELECT concat('No Users Found: ', Customer_Name);
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data showing what you expect to get versus what you are actually getting?

Comment: What kind of column naming is User ID?

Comment: You seem to have named your parameter `Email` the same as the column, `Email`. Try changing the parameter name to something else.

Comment: @almasshaikh Definitely not a good choice of field name, but as long as it's quoted like that, it works.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewBarber I didnt knew you could use space in column but you made my day. Yeppy i learned new thing today :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem no doubt lies here:

```
SELECT `User ID` INTO User_ID FROM `Users` WHERE `Email` = Email LIMIT 1;
```

To whit; your parameter name is the same as your column name. That *can* actually work, but the rules to make it do so can be weird. (I think if you switched the quotes around, it might work).

But really, what you should do is rename the `Email` parameter to something else:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`myusername`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `User_Auth`(IN `EmailAddress` VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    DECLARE User_ID INT(30);
        SELECT `User ID` INTO User_ID FROM `Users` WHERE `Email` = EmailAddress  LIMIT 1;

    IF (User_ID > 0) THEN
        SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `User ID` = User_ID;
    ELSE
        SELECT concat('No Users Found: ', Customer_Name);
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your variable has the name `email`, the same as the column.  So, `email = email` is basically a no-op, because it refers only to the column name.

It is a good idea to prefix parameters with something to avoid this confusion:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`myusername`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `User_Auth`(IN v_Email VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_User_ID INT(30);
    SELECT `User ID` INTO User_ID FROM `Users` u WHERE u.Email = v_Email LIMIT 1;

    IF (User_ID > 0) THEN
        SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `User ID` = v_User_ID;
    ELSE
        SELECT concat('No Users Found: ', Customer_Name);
    END IF;
END
```